# How to paste in windows wsl without using mouse?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently I installed Ubuntu WSL in windows, but I can't paste text to the terminal using keyboard(like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> before). I can use right click to paste, but it's just inconvenient. Is there a way that I can use keyboard for copy/paste?

ps: Windows Subsystem for Linux, not cmd prompt. I can't use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> here.

Answer (score 5):

As cited in the [Microsoft command line blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/04/13/copy-and-paste-arrives-for-linuxwsl-consoles/):

> As of **Windows 10 Insider build #17643**, you can copy/paste text from/to Linux/WSL Consoles!!!
>   To ensure that we don't break any existing behaviors, you'll need to enable the "`Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste` option in the Console `Options` properties page:

[image: WSL enable copy paste option on terminal]